# error while making url non casesensitive

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have to make the url non case sentitive.Now it shows an error 404 not found

so i included .htaccess file and include the below code in it

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and also include 404.php and include the below code

```
$lower = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$new = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $lower;

if (file_exists(ltrim($lower, '/')) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != $lower)
{ 
    header("Location: $new"); 
    exit; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'Page not found'; 
}
```

Now it doesn't shows 404 not found error.but if we put lowercase in the url it redirects to home page.any idea?

Comment: Please, *either* indent your code to mark it as code (preferred) *or* use HTML entities. Not *both*!

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what you want. You want your site to respond to both `/action` and `/Action`, is that correct?

Comment: i try the above code..but now it shows 404 not found error

Comment: Use `SERVER_NAME` instead of `HTTP_HOST`. This probably won't solve your problem but it will help other potential problems. @Frankie, that is exactly what he/she wants.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton thks, then check my answer. It bypasses PHP altogether and goes straight to the source. Apache.

Comment: i want to make the url non case sensitive..for eg if we type www.acc.com/ACYCLOVIR_CREAM.php or  www.acc.com/acyclovir_cream.php, both need to work.

Comment: Aren't Windows servers case-insensitive? :D

Comment: @Frankie yes i want to make site to respond to both /action and /Action

Answer (score 1):

To make Apache behave case-insensitive you should use the following setup:

```
 // on httpd.conf
 LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
 CheckCaseOnly on
```

I wouldn't recommend it and would instead throw the user a 404 with suggested similar pages.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be a `RewriteMap` rule that can lowercase the incoming paths for you. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int (Should be available for 2.2 too).

You basically only need to check if the URL exsists, otherwise lowercase it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) ${lowercase:$1} [R]
```

Or something like that.

Comment: @asitha you can include it on your .htaccess file or your httpd.conf file assuming you're running your site on Apache. This is leaning to serverfault.com...

Comment: i included the above code in .htaccess then got error "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: Try with the edited version. If it still doesn't work... do you have full access to the server? Probably means that the server admin (the one that configured Apache - assuming you are running on Apache) does not let you mess with some directives (possibly RewriteMap?)